# Remove querysubmitted handler from searchpane

Tags: search, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

Following the many online examples I have implemented search in a Metro app by attaching a handler to the search pane of the application:

```
public void DoSearch() {
    var mySearchPane = SearchPane.GetForCurrentView();
    if (null == mySearchPane) return;
    mySearchPane.QuerySubmitted +=
        new TypedEventHandler<SearchPane, SearchPaneQuerySubmittedEventArgs>(OnQuerySubmitted);
    mySearchPane.Show();
}

private void OnQuerySubmitted(...) {
    // ...blah, blah
}
```

Question: Does the handler for the QuerySubmitted event eventually need to be removed after the search is over? If it does have to be removed then how can I remove the event handler after the search is completed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are wiring up a specific user action, like a button click, to initiate a search, including wiring into the Search events.  This is not the correct approach.

You would want to call `SearchPane.GetForCurrentView` and hook into the `QuerySubmitted` event one time when your page is created. A user can invoke the Charm bar at anytime and peform a search.  If my assumption is correct, your app would not be able to handle that scenario.

I you want to open the search pane from the UX (generally not a good UX practice btw), then you would want to set up mySearchPane as a class variable that can be accessible to the rest of the page at anytime and call `mySearchPane.Show()` from inside your click handler as you do now.

If you handle things this way, there is no need to worry about disconnecting the `QuerySubmitted` handler since the handlers will be cleaned up when you navigate away from the page.